# How can I label the values in a boxplot with GD::Graph?

Tags: perl, boxplot, gd-graph

How can I label the values in a boxplot with [GD::Graph](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD::Graph)?

[`show_values`](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD::Graph#show_values) doesn't help me.

Comment: Are you using [GD::Graph::boxplot](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD::Graph::boxplot)? If so, I think `show_values` is broken because GD::Graph::boxplot uses a different format for data than other graph types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am using GD::Graph::boxplot. If show_values is   broken then is there any other way. I am just stuck at this stage where I can't represent the data points?

Comment: You can try [submitting a bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Report.html?Queue=GDGraph-boxplot) to the maintainer of GD::Graph::boxplot, but since the last release was in 2001, it doesn't appear to be actively maintained. I would recommend switching to a different graphing package like [Chart::Clicker](https://metacpan.org/pod/Chart::Clicker).